# No primary or candidate keys in the referenced table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting an error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'TProducts' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'TProducts_TCategories_FK'."

When trying to establish a relationship between my products table and categories table. I have checked the spelling multiple times but can't seem to figure out why I keep getting this error. The rest of my tables are fine, and I used the same method.

```
CREATE TABLE TCategories
(
    intCategoryID   INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    strCategoryName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT TCategories_PK PRIMARY KEY (intCategoryID)
)

CREATE TABLE TProducts
(
    intProductID     INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    intVendorID      INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    intCategoryID    INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    strProductName   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    monCostofProduct MONEY        NOT NULL,
    monRetailCost    MONEY        NOT NULL,
    intInventory     INTEGER      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT TProducts_PK PRIMARY KEY (intProductID)
)

ALTER TABLE TProducts    
    ADD CONSTRAINT TProducts_TCategories_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (intCategoryID) REFERENCES TProducts (intCategoryID)
```

Comment: `REFERENCES TProducts`? Shouldn't that be `dbo.TCategories`?

Comment: Yup...that was it. Thank you, I need to look more carefully

Comment: Just stop using that ridiculous naming pattern of including "type" as a preface to every name.

Comment: Also `money` should be avoided, it has serious problems with rounding errors

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to TProducts table and not TCategories table:

```
ALTER TABLE TProducts    ADD CONSTRAINT TProducts_TCategories_FK 
FOREIGN KEY ( intCategoryID ) REFERENCES TCategories( intCategoryID )
```